# Create bar chart with bar summ up to 100

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I try to create a bar chart in LaTeX with PGFPLOTS with the bars that **sum up to 100%**.

The lower part (let's say 30%) shall be green.

The middle part (let's say 20%) shall be yello.

The upper part (let's say 50%) shall be red.

I can produce plots side by side with these numbers, but not **stacked**.

Has anybody an idea how to tackle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows us what you already tried?

Comment: Have a look at section "4.5.9 Stacked Plots" of the user guide

Comment: @Cyoux You asked a question as if you only want three bars, stacked top to bottom with varying sizes and colored red, yellow and green from top to bottom respectively. Is that what you want?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You made my day! You really spelled this out for me.
Of course I had a look into the manual, but did not see 4.5.9. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @Cyoux You're welcome! Maybe you could write up a short answer with an example so future users with the same problem can find it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the manual of pgfplots in "4.5.9 Stacked Plots". (Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for the hint)

The code I use from this manual chapter ist this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
  \addplotcoordinates{(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
  \addplotcoordinates{(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
  \addplotcoordinates{(0,1) (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```